# Traveling by plane within Mexico without a passport

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, mexico

I have permanent residency in Mexico, my FM 3 visa, however my passport is expired. Can I still board a domestic flight using my FM 3 visa? My flight is from Guadalajara to Puebla.

Comment: Does your FM3 have a picture? [Aeromexico](https://aeromexico.com/es-mx/informacion-de-vuelos/documentos-para-viajar) indicates that an FM3 visa with picture is an acceptable travel document for domestic flights

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza that sounds like an answer!

Comment: I think both the question and the Aeromexico web site are a little confused. The FM3 (a passport-size book) went away quite a few years ago, and was replaced by a Temporary Resident card. There is also a Permanent Resident card (replacing the old FM2). Either of those cards will get one on a domestic flight, but I think the OP needs to clarify what the document is.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I did it last year, traveling from Mexico City to La Paz (BCS) with Aeromexico. I am a temporal resident (student with a TRTE/FM1). However, it is difficult to find clear information about it.

On the [Aeromexico website](https://aeromexico.com/es-mx/informacion-de-vuelos/documentos-para-viajar) you can see:

> Identificaciones válidas para *pasajeros mexicanos* en vuelos nacionales
> Para efectos de abordaje de vuelos nacionales se consideran como
> válidas, las siguientes identificaciones:
>
> - Credencial del IMSS con fotografía
> - FM3 con fotografía
> - Carta de vecindad con fotografía, membrete y sello del municipio
> - Pasaporte vigente
> - Matrícula consular
> - Licencia de conducir vigente
> - Cédula profesional
> - Carta de servicio militar
> - Credencial de elector vigente
> - Credencial del INSEN
> - Credencial de cámara de senadores y diputados
> - Certificado presunción de nacionalidad mexicana
> - Tarjeta única de identidad militar

However, there is no clear mention of foreigners with temporal or permanent residency, as it only says "Mexican passengers".

The same goes with [Viva Aerobus](https://web.vivaaerobus.com/mx/info/terminos-y-condiciones): they only mention foreigners when it comes to [entering the country](https://www.vivaaerobus.com/es-mx/info/preparate-para-volar/documentos-para-viajar/viajando-a-mexico).

> El Pasajero deberá presentar una Identificación Oficial con
> fotografía, original y vigente, así como su Pase de Abordar.

Finally, **[Volaris](https://cms.volaris.com/es/informacion-util/antes-de-tu-vuelo/documentos-y-requisitos-de-viaje/)** is of more help:

> **Documentos de identificación y migratorios para viajar a México**
>
> **Vuelos dentro de México**
>
> [...]
>
> **Extranjeros: una identificación oficial vigente con fotografía
> original en físico (no fotocopias ni digital).**
>
> - Pasaporte vigente
> - Residencia vigente
> - Alguna otra identificación oficial vigente

(And Interjet is dead)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).